# xCode returns 'timed out waiting for app to launch' error when I trying deploy PhoneGAP app on the device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

I tried to deploy PhoneGAP HelloWorld test app on the device.
I am using XCode 4.6/iOS 6.1 SDK  and I want to deploy app on the iOS 5.1.1 device.
The Project is in debug mode.
When I tried it, xCode returned `timed out waiting for app to launch` error.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 10):

Changing the AdHoc Provisioning for a standard Development / Team Provisioning worked for me.

Comment: Strangely, I had my provisioning profile set to an enterprise distribution profile instead of a development profile.

Comment: worked for me. Now in xcode 6 you have to change to distribution provisioning profile to distribute app. In my case I had to change again the provisioning profile to development and run app. Change this in Build Settings.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I was using an ad hoc profile for debugging. Try with development profile and it will work. Ad hoc works unexpectedly for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to turn off ad-hoc provisioning profile.

Answer (score 2):

Check in your code perhaps you use Adhoc provisioning profile in debug mode. If your problem

is not solve then restart your device. Sometimes this type of behavior is seen.

Comment: Also clean your Xcode & delete unnecessary apps from device & then restart your device & check.